# Rayleigh Scattering VS Raman Scattering

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, scattering

When studying incidental photons, when should I use elastic scattering (Rayleigh scattering) and when inelastic scattering (Raman Scattering)?

What is the application of each of them?

Comment: The main difference between them is that Rayleigh scattering is elastic, meaning that the scattered light has the same energy and wavelength as the incident light, while Raman scattering is inelastic, meaning that the scattered light has a different energy and wavelength than the incident light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are always both happening, but Raman scattering is several orders of magnitude weaker, so you can generally ignore it if you’re not looking for it specifically.

Comment: About application, we can mention spectroscopy for Raman as mentioned on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raman_scattering).

Comment: @JohnB indeed, I considered adding something about the applications of Raman spectroscopy, but I did want to put in the effort. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

When photons are scattered, most of them are elastically scattered (Rayleigh scattering), such that the scattered photons have the same energy (frequency, wavelength and color). An even smaller fraction of the scattered photons can be scattered inelastically, with the scattered photons having an energy different (usually lower) from those of the incident photons.

Comment: "... inelastically, with the scattered photons having an energy different ..." Can a change of angle, i.e. direction of the incoming photon transfer into energy of the electron?